# Clean Install MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a 13" MacBook Pro that Apple has lent me while my new 15" is being built and I need to restore it to the same condition as the day I received it from Apple. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by shutting down your computer, then when you turn it on press and hold <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and wait a while (normally about 5 mins)

Once your in Internet Recovery go to `disk utility` and format your drive. After you have done that go to `Install OS X` and follow the instructions. This will create an clean install. Once you do that shutdown the computer and then you can give it back to them. Don't do the setup.